# Session does not work from Exception Handler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need redirect user to the homepage with a flash message when some exception are throw but I can't access message flashed from Exception handler. This is my code :

```
  if(config('app.env') == 'production')
    {
        if($exception instanceof FatalErrorException ||
            $exception instanceof FatalThrowableError
        ){
            return redirect(route('home'))->with('message',
                [
                    'type' => 'info',
                    'content' => 'Nous nous excusons pour cette gène ! 
                    Notre équipe technique est informée du problème et passera
                    à la correction dans le plus brefs délais que possible
                    '
            ]);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

What is the problem ?

I access the flashed message like this :

```
        @if(session()->has('message'))
            <div data-toggle="alert-dismissable" role="alert" class="alert alert-{{ session('message')['type'] ?? 'success' }}">
                <i class="fa fa-{{ session('message')['type'] ?? 'success' }}"></i>
                {{ session('message')['content'] ?? session('message') }}
            </div>
        @endif
```

Comment: post your form code

Comment: How are you accessing the flashed message?

Comment: I rewrited the question @TahirRaza

Comment: I just implemented your code in new Laravel 5.4 and it's working fine, please have a look at this [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/ii9qbl).

Comment: How you are getting this variable `$exception`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to user `session()` instead of `with` the value in session you can do this with:

```
 if(config('app.env') == 'production')
{
    if($exception instanceof FatalErrorException ||
        $exception instanceof FatalThrowableError
    ){

       session()->flash('message', [
                'type' => 'info',
                'content' => 'Nous nous excusons pour cette gène ! 
                Notre équipe technique est informée du problème et passera
                à la correction dans le plus brefs délais que possible
                '
        ]);

        return redirect(route('home'));
    }
}

return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

if you want to use `with()` then you have to change your view

```
 @if(isset($message))
        <div data-toggle="alert-dismissable" role="alert" class="alert alert-{{ $message['type'] ?? 'success' }}">
            <i class="fa fa-{{ $message['type'] ?? 'success' }}"></i>
            {{ $message['content'] ?? $message['content'] }}
        </div>
    @endif
```

Hope this helps