# Cannot get Session message from Handler class laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

What I try to do is to get a message in the session when redirecting back to the page from exception handler class, When I get 'PostTooLargeException' It should back to page with a message.

**If statement in Handler class**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        //...

        if ($exception instanceof PostTooLargeException) {


           $test = redirect()->route('clientbank.create')->with('message', 'File too large!'); //Cannot get message
           return $test;
           //dump($gg);
           dump(session('message'));
           dd('stop');

        }
        // this will still show the error if there is any in your code.

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

In `dump(session('message'));` I can see the message .

[image]

**In blade page**

```
   @elseif(session('message'))
     <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
       {{ session('message') }}
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
     </div>
   @endif
```

**In controller**

```
 public function create()
    {
        dump(session('message')); <-- getting null !!!
        return view('clinetbank.bank.cratebank');
    }
```

What I try to do is use `empyt(session('message')` I always get an empty session.

Also, I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922603/session-does-not-work-from-exception-handler) questions but not work for me.

I use laravel 5.8

Any ideas, please ?.

Comment: Where do you return $test to?

Comment: @ColinMD it return when I get ```posttolarngexpiton``` and it should return to this route in controller create function ```clientbank.create``` it work  but without session message.

Comment: I find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650234/handling-posttoolargeexception-in-laravel-5-5)

Comment: same here, you got no solution? :(